# Remove '\n' from columns in Hive tables

Tags: hive

I a table called `Table1` in a Hive database which is stored using parquet and I need to copy data from this table to a table which is stored as a text file.  For this purpose I used the query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/sbt-dobrov-da/db/external/custom_rb_loan/agrmnt_bal' 
TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = '')
```

Everything works well but if `Table1` contains `'\n'` in its column data, I cannot parse my text file from `/db/table2` because it cannot find the correct strings.

My question is:

Is there a way to account for the `'\n'` in my text file?

Comment: Are you saying you have `\n' within your data, not just as line terminators?

Comment: `SELECT a, b, TRANSLATE(c, '\n\r', ''), TRANSLATE(d, '\n\r', '')` would remove all LF and CR characters from columns `c` and `d`. Or you could replace LF with some special character and remove CR, with `¶`, etc. Cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: @Andrew, yes i have '\n' within data in columns

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, thak you, but i don't want to use any SQL function in my Query and modify data, but it's looks like it's only one way to solve it and added TRANSLATE function, but i don't realy khow what happens with my performance after that

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem like @SamsonScharfrichter said. In my SQL statment when i use String datatype i use TRANSLATE(c, '\n\r', '') function and all works fine. Thanks a lot